# python script not running from flask application

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

my flask app does not appear to be executing external python scripts.

flask code:

```py
#!/bin/python3
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('action1') == 'VALUE1':

         def run_script():
           file = open(r'/doorop.py', 'r').read()
           return exec(file)
        elif  request.form.get('action2') == 'VALUE2':

         def run_script():
           file = open(r'/doorcl.py', 'r').read()
           return exec(file)
        else:
            pass
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)

    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000', debug=True)
```

html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 8</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/">
            <input type="submit" value="Open" name="action1"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Close" name="action2"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

python code for doorop.py:

```py
#!/bin/python3
# open pi door program

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
from time import sleep


#define GPIO pins
GPIO.setwarnings(False)                         # Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                          # Use physical pin numbering
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)       # Set pin 5 to be 'direction'
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)       # Set pin 6 to be 'step' 
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)     # Set pin 21 to control relay

count = 1

#while True: # Run forever
while count < 4000:
        GPIO.output(5, GPIO.HIGH)               # Open
        GPIO.output(6, GPIO.HIGH)               # Turn on
        sleep(.0005)                            # Sleep for 1 second
        GPIO.output(6, GPIO.LOW)                # Turn off
        sleep(.0010)
        count += 1

# good practise to cleanup GPIO at some point before exiting
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated !
gb

when pressing the html button, i would like the flask app to execute the python script associated to the button. the python programs do execute correctly from the command line.

Comment: With `def run_script()m` you are merely *defining* a function, but not actually *calling* it.

Comment: not been able to find the way to do that, (calling the function) multiple searches, no joy. will continue attempting.... thanks for the insight....

Comment: could anyone help me on how to call the function from the run_script?  I am unable to find anything other than the python tutorial, and that is so complex that the answer is not forthcoming. This raspberry pi server runs inside my house, not exposed to the outside network, I have a firewall, so security is not a problem.

Comment: Try removing the 2 lines `def run_script():` and correct the indentation and it should work fine.